# Inserting a CSS id into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic .each statement of comments and at the bottom of them is a form to add a new comment.  The goal is simple yet I've tried quite a bit and cannot get it to work.  When someone submits a comment in the form I'd like that comment to show up just above and have it move the form down, using jQuery.  This is working fine, but I have 2 problems.

1. I need the new comment that is being displayed by jQuery to inherit a CSS class called triangle-right.
2. I need the form to clear, it keeps the last comment in there after submit.

Here is the jQuery.  Again, I need @comment.recommendation to display using the CSS class triangle-right and for the form to clear.  #newrec is the form.

```
$('#newrec').before('<%= escape_javascript(@comment.recommendation) %>');
```

In case it is helpful, here is the view.

```
<% recs.each do |r| %>
    <% name = User.find_by(:id => r.user_id)%>

    <p class = "triangle-right" id ="comment_<%=r.id%>">
      <b><%=name.first_name.capitalize %> <%=name.last_name.capitalize %></b>:    <%=r.recommendation %></br></br>

    <%= link_to '<i class="icon-edit"></i>'.html_safe, edit_comment_url(r),class:"btn btn-warning" if current_user.present? && r.user_id == current_user.id %>

    <%= link_to '<i class="icon-trash"></i>'.html_safe, comment_url(r), class:"btn btn-danger", method: 'delete', remote: true if current_user.present? && r.user_id == current_user.id %>

    </p>
  <%end%>
    <!-- LIST OF RECOMMENDATIONS IS ABOVE -->
    <!-- FORM FOR RECS BELOW -->
  <div>
    <%= form_tag(commentpost_url, id: "newrec", method: 'post', remote: true) do %>
      <h4><%= "Give your recommendations:" if current_user.present? %></h4>
      <%= text_area_tag :recommendation, nil, class: "rectextarea", id: "new_rec" if current_user.present? %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :trip_detail_id, d.id %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id if current_user.present?%>

    <div>
      <% if current_user.present? && @trip.userid == current_user.id %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-large btn-success" if current_user.present? %>
      <%else%>
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit Recs!', class: "btn btn-large btn-success" if current_user.present? %>
      <%end%>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

And finally the controller

```
def create
@comment = Comment.new
@comment.recommendation = params[:recommendation]
@comment.trip_detail_id = params[:trip_detail_id]
@comment.user_id = params[:user_id]

if @comment.save

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Rec was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
   format.js
  end

else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

Thanks!

Comment: Please show full code related to this issue. You've already shown js.erb, please show View template and controller code. Besides, what is "recommendation"?

Comment: I will go ahead and add the code.  recommendation is a text column in the comment table in my rails app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. If you want to add new comment to show, the comments are expect to be a list, . Revise this accordingly.
2. Extract your comment showing part, the `<li>` part into a partial.
3. Extract the form part into a partial
4. render these partial in view template to replace previous parts.
5. render these two partial again in js

The pseudo js code like this

```
$('ul#comments').append('<%=j render partial: "comment", locals: {comment: @comment}')
$('#comment_form').html('<%=j render partial: "comment_form", 
                                              locals: {comment: Comment.new)')
```

*P.S You code really need to improvement. Too much logic in view, and too much unconventional stuff.*